# Ошибка 'callback'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Ошибка

```
TypeError: register_next_step_handler() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback'
```

Я понимаю что он хочет увидеть `callback`, но я не понимаю что это и куда я должен записать этот
`callback` в интернете нету описания что это, в документации тоже не нашел.

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text in ["Новосибирская 16В"])
def repeat_all_messages(message: types.Message):
    msg = bot.reply_to(message, "Введите продажу через дефис в виде [КАТЕГОРИЯ-НАЗВАНИЕ-ЦЕНА-СПОСОБ ОПЛАТЫ]:")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg) #запоминает последнее введенное сообщение

def process_name_step(message):
    try:
        today = date.today().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")

        category, nazvanie, price, cpocob_oplata = message.text.split("-", 3)
        text_message = f'На {today} в таблицу добавлена запись:'
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text_message)

        sh = gc.open_by_url(googlesheet_id) # открываем Google таблицу и добавляем запись
        sh.sheet1.append_row([today, category, nazvanie, price, cpocob_oplata])
    except:
    # если пользователь ввел неправильную информацию, оповещаем его и просим вводить повторно
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ОШИБКА! Неправильный формат данных!')

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите продажу через дефис в виде [КАТЕГОРИЯ-НАЗВАНИЕ-ЦЕНА-СПОСОБ ОПЛАТЫ]:')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text in ["Новосибирская 16В"])
def repeat_all_messages(message: types.Message):
    # не обязательно записывать месседж в переменную если уже есть обьект месседж
    bot.reply_to(message, "Введите продажу через дефис в виде [КАТЕГОРИЯ-НАЗВАНИЕ-ЦЕНА-СПОСОБ ОПЛАТЫ]:")
    # нужно указать название функции которая сработает при следующем сообщении от юзера
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_name_step)
```